# How to increment values in a matrix using 3 for loops in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `by_property_arranged` where `products` is a column of product combinations with each product separated by a comma:

```
structure(list(products = c("AC, ACH", "AC, ACH, HS", "AC, EEW", 
"AC, EEW, ESH, HS, IEW, IPD, SSL, WH, WSL", "AC, EEW, ESH, HS, IEW, SSL, WSL", 
"AC, EEW, ESH, IEW, IGL, SSL, WSL", "AC, EEW, HPS, HS", "AC, EEW, HPS, HS, WSL", 
"AC, EEW, HPS, IEW, SSL, WH, WSL", "AC, EEW, HS", "AC, EEW, HS, IEW", 
"AC, EEW, HS, IEW, IGL", "AC, EEW, HS, IEW, IGL, ILV, SSL, WH, WSL", 
"AC, EEW, HS, IEW, IGL, ILV, WH", "AC, EEW, HS, IEW, IGL, IPD, SSL, WH, WSL"
), occurences = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("products", "occurences"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have created an empty matrix like so:

```
pop_matrix <- matrix(,nrow=17,ncol=17,dimnames = list(names))

colnames(pop_matrix) <- names

pop_matrix[is.na(pop_matrix)] <- 0
```

Where `names` is a vector of all product names like so:

```
c("WSL", "EEW", "SSL", "AC", "IPD", "WH", "IEW", "ESH", "HS", 
"IGL", "ACH", "IEWE", "ESL", "ILV", "HPS", "ID", "IR")
```

What I would like to do is increment each value in this matrix if both a colname and a rowname exist in a row of the `by_property_arranged` dataframe. My code is as follows:

```
 for (k in 1:nrow(by_property_arranged[1])){
      for (i in 1:length(colnames(pop_matrix))) {
        for (j in 1:length(rownames(pop_matrix))) { 
          if(grepl(colnames(pop_matrix)[i],by_property_arranged[k,1]) &&
          grepl(rownames(pop_matrix)[j],by_property_arranged[k,1])) {

            pop_matrix[i,j] =+ 1

          }          
        }
      }
    }
```

All I get is a matrix of 1's in which is not true. The values in the matrix are not incrementing as expected. The reason I am doing this is to see products with the most common relationships.

The expected output would be a matrix with the correct number of occurrences of two products in each row of `by_property_arranged`. Something like this:

```
structure(c(6, 7, 4, 13, 13, 13, 15, 6, 6, 11, 7, 4, 3, 9, 12, 
3, 5, 7, 14, 3, 4, 1, 10, 10, 8, 13, 10, 11, 2, 8, 8, 10, 8, 
15, 4, 3, 6, 1, 12, 14, 10, 15, 7, 2, 10, 7, 3, 9, 9, 1, 4, 13, 
4, 1, 1, 15, 15, 4, 11, 1, 7, 15, 11, 13, 5, 3, 6, 4, 13, 1, 
12, 15, 4, 2, 3, 10, 3, 9, 13, 2, 1, 7, 5, 11, 8, 13, 10, 14, 
15, 2, 6, 5, 10, 1, 14, 2, 1, 2, 9, 13, 11, 5, 15, 10, 10, 4, 
3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1, 7, 6, 13, 8, 8, 13, 5, 6, 8, 15, 11, 10, 10, 
7, 4, 11, 11, 7, 13, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 13, 7, 1, 3, 1, 7, 11, 
7, 8, 14, 11, 7, 5, 14, 3, 12, 11, 10, 2, 7, 9, 14, 1, 11, 8, 
15, 1, 5, 9, 4, 9, 1, 7, 7, 11, 10, 15, 13, 2, 7, 7, 14, 1, 14, 
11, 5, 1, 12, 1, 12, 4, 2, 7, 11, 2, 1, 6, 13, 11, 5, 11, 5, 
7, 5, 8, 11, 3, 3, 8, 3, 13, 1, 2, 13, 2, 7, 9, 5, 7, 7, 8, 13, 
11, 2, 9, 8, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 8, 7, 14, 7, 9, 12, 
10, 9, 3, 5, 13, 8, 3, 14, 9, 12, 8, 13, 14, 9, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 
6, 11, 11, 13, 5, 3, 1, 1, 11, 11, 7, 2, 3, 14, 5, 15, 4, 4, 
8, 5, 5, 7, 12, 7, 12, 3, 2, 9, 5, 14, 10), .Dim = c(17L, 17L
), .Dimnames = list(c("WSL", "EEW", "SSL", "AC", "IPD", "WH", 
"IEW", "ESH", "HS", "IGL", "ACH", "IEWE", "ESL", "ILV", "HPS", 
"ID", "IR"), c("WSL", "EEW", "SSL", "AC", "IPD", "WH", "IEW", 
"ESH", "HS", "IGL", "ACH", "IEWE", "ESL", "ILV", "HPS", "ID", 
"IR")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `pop_matrix`, then we can do,

```
sapply(rownames(pop_matrix), function(i) 
            sapply(colnames(pop_matrix), function(j) 
                   length(intersect(grep(i, d1$products), grep(j, d1$products)))))

#     WSL EEW SSL AC IPD WH IEW ESH HS IGL ACH IEWE ESL ILV HPS ID IR
#WSL    7   7   6  7   2  4   6   3  5   3   0    0   0   1   2  0  0
#EEW    7  13   6 13   2  5   9   3 10   5   0    0   0   2   3  0  0
#SSL    6   6   6  6   2  4   6   3  4   3   0    0   0   1   1  0  0
#AC     7  13   6 15   2  5   9   3 11   5   2    0   0   2   3  0  0
#IPD    2   2   2  2   2  2   2   1  2   1   0    0   0   0   0  0  0
#WH     4   5   4  5   2  5   5   1  4   3   0    0   0   2   1  0  0
#IEW    6   9   6  9   2  5   9   3  7   5   0    0   0   2   1  0  0
#ESH    3   3   3  3   1  1   3   3  2   1   0    0   0   0   0  0  0
#HS     5  10   4 11   2  4   7   2 11   4   1    0   0   2   2  0  0
#IGL    3   5   3  5   1  3   5   1  4   5   0    0   0   2   0  0  0
#ACH    0   0   0  2   0  0   0   0  1   0   2    0   0   0   0  0  0
#IEWE   0   0   0  0   0  0   0   0  0   0   0    0   0   0   0  0  0
#ESL    0   0   0  0   0  0   0   0  0   0   0    0   0   0   0  0  0
#ILV    1   2   1  2   0  2   2   0  2   2   0    0   0   2   0  0  0
#HPS    2   3   1  3   0  1   1   0  2   0   0    0   0   0   3  0  0
#ID     0   0   0  0   0  0   0   0  0   0   0    0   0   0   0  0  0
#IR     0   0   0  0   0  0   0   0  0   0   0    0   0   0   0  0  0
```

However, the resulting values don't agree with your expected output so do check it carefully.